# err="not authorized to sign: 0x00000000000000000000000f07A0b446F09afad7" | admin.addPeer("enode") returns true with no result

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, blockchain, ethereum

I'm trying to create two docker containers that will hold [GoChain nodes](https://github.com/gochain/docs/tree/master/private-networks/custom) for each one of them.

Everything goes well until I build the solution up with `docker-compose up -d`, both containers are running the nodes but one of them (the second) shows an error when `docker logs -f node2` is executed :

> err="not authorized to sign:
> 0x00000000000000000000000f07A0b446F09afad7"

Also, when I try to add another peer to the first node by executing `admin.addPeers("enode://enode2adress@node2IP")`, the only response I get is `true` but no peers were added when I check with `admin.peers`, it returns an empty array.

Where could the source of the problem be ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER :

`Genesis.json` file must have the second address as a signer.